# PHP increase image resolution from url and then crop

Tags: php

I have images with resolution of 720x1280 and I would need to store them on server with resolution 800x1500.
Since 720x1280 increased to height 1500 gives resolution of 844x1500 I would also need to crop image, remove 22 pixels from the left and right side.

For now I have this:

```
$img_url = file_get_contents($url);

$img = imagecreatefromstring($img_url);

$width = imagesx($img);
$height = imagesy($img);

$new_width = '800';
$new_height = '1500';

$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

imagecopyresampled($thumb, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

imagejpeg($thumb, $name, 100);

imagedestroy($thumb);
imagedestroy($img);
```

But the problem is that image is not cropped, 22 pixels from the left and right side are not removed.

Is there a way to do this, to first increase image resolution from url and then crop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling `php image crop` reveals [the secret](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecrop.php):

```
$rect = [22, 0, 800, 1500]
$thumb = imagecrop($thumb, $rect)
```

Comment: In this case you'd need to set `$new_width = '844';` first, then crop.

Comment: Right, that would be correct. I'm just answering the OP's question about cropping, there are enough other things wrong with the code.

Comment: Thanks, it's just what I needed! Can you tell me what other things are wrong with the code?

Comment: Well, you use strings instead of ints for the dimensions, and you deform the image by changing the proportions in the first step, as @cyborg points out. But above all your code can only transform images with these exact dimensions, although it would have been easy to write the core parts in a more general way. (This is poor design, not an error exactly.)

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
imagecopyresampled($thumb, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
```

you just scale your original image to new dimensions.
As the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) says:

> If the source and destination coordinates and width and heights differ, appropriate stretching or shrinking of the image fragment will be performed.

You need to set:

```
$shiftX = 22*(1280/1500); // consider passing variables rather than constant values
$scaledWidth = 720-$shiftX*2;
imagecopyresampled($thumb, $img, 0, 0, $shiftX, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $scaledWidth, $height);
```

which cuts out the required (proportional) rectangle of the source image to paste it in you destination picture.